# Clojure protocol/function priority

Tags: clojure

Working with Clojure, we have the following:

```
(defprotocol Greeter (hello [args] "Say hello"))

(extend-protocol Greeter
   String
   (hello [this] (str "Hello " this)))

(hello "world")    ; "Hello world"
```

So far, so good. Then we add:

```
(defn hello [args] (str "Wassup " args "?"))
```

Which changes the output of the previous form to:

```
(hello "world")    ; "Wassup world?"
```

Is there a way to make the protocol take priority over the function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to make the protocol take priority over the method?

You can't mesh `defn` with `defprotocol`. This is because `defprotocol` actually generates a binding for a function in your current namespace. Notice the warning you get when you run your code in this order:

```
user=> (defn hello [args] (str "Wassup " args "?"))
#'user/hello
user=> (defprotocol Greeter (hello [args] "Say hello"))
Warning: protocol #'user/Greeter is overwriting function hello
Greeter
```

The [Protocols documentation](http://clojure.org/protocols) explains that the correct way to provide a default implementation is to use `Object`:

```
(defprotocol Greeter (hello [args] "Say hello"))

(extend-protocol Greeter
   Object
   (hello [this] (str "Wassup " this "?")))

(extend-protocol Greeter
   String
   (hello [this] (str "Hello " this)))

(hello "world")    ; "Hello world"

(hello 1)    ; "Wassup 1?"
```

Answer (score 2):

Protocol methods *are* functions, so like any other var, if you want to have two of them with the same name you have to put them in a separate namespace.